# При добавлении NinjectModule перестают работать EditorFor для целых чисел

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

После добавления NinjectModule

```
public class GameNinjectRegistration : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IGameRepo>().To<GameRepo>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}    
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ....
    NinjectModule reg = new GameNinjectRegistration();
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(reg);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

Начинает появляться следующая ошибка при попытке использовать @Html.EditorFor.

**Ошибка:**
Имена типов проверки в ненавязчивых правилах проверки должны быть уникальными. Следующие типы проверки встречаются более одного раза: required

В чем ошибка?

Без модуля все работает нормально

**Представление**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Модель**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1,100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
    // GET: Movies2/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
```

Comment: `Следующие типы проверки встречаются более одного раза: required` ?

Comment: ну так вы не привели ни модель, ни поле из модели, на которой ошибка вылетает

Comment: Ругается на поле ID у модели в представлении вылетает ошибка на строке @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID). Если убрать поле из представления, то ругаться будет на другие поля